# Sum and lookup over range in spreadsheet

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a google spreadsheet that looks like this

**Items**

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 12 |
| C | 15 |
| D | 20 |

**Calc**

| Total | Items |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A |  |  |
|  | A | B |  |
|  | A | A |  |
|  | C | C | C |

In `Total` I want to have the a formula that sums the value of the items, so the results would be:

```
10
22
20
45
```

There is always a row in **Items** for any item in **Calc**

The number of items in **Calc** will be between 1 and 15

I've tried formulas like `=sum(lookup(C2:G2, Items!$A$2:$B$5000))` and `=sum(sumifs(Items!$B$2:$B$5000,Items!$A$2:$A$5000,C2:G2))` but I can't find anything that can operate on a range

Comment: Hi Ray. It looks like the number of columns is variable. Is there a limit to the number of columns you don't expect to exceed?

Comment: @DaveWhite Probably 15 would be the most

Comment: The items could be stored in cell, e.g. `A,B,C,C` if that's easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Not the most elegant or pretty solution but what you can do:

Assuming the **Items** range is C3:D6, you can write the following formula at the next column next to the range that you want so, for example, if your range for the first row is C11:Q11 you would place this formula in R11

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(C11,$C$3:$D$6,2,false),0)
```

then you would copy and paste (to the right) this formula for as many columns as you need (e.g. 15) and then copy the entire row of formulas you just created for as many rows as needed.

These would be helper columns.

Under your **Total** column you would just need to sum the range of those helper columns, so assuming the top row to be counted is C11:Q11 and the helper range is R11:AF11, the corresponding total formula would be `=sum(R11:AF11)`

**Option 2**

This is the same approach as Option 1 but consolidates all the formulas in one column. It has the advantage of keeping the rest of the spreadsheet free of helper columns, but it increases the in-cell formula complexity:

In the **Total** column you combine the sum of the helper columns used in Option 1 so that, for example, if your range for the first row is C11:Q11, you would have the following formula on the corresponding Total column

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(C11,$C$3:$D$6,2,false),0)+iferror(VLOOKUP(D11,$C$3:$D$6,2,false),0)+iferror(VLOOKUP(E11,$C$3:$D$6,2,false),0)+iferror(VLOOKUP(F11,$C$3:$D$6,2,false),0)
```

The example formula here sums only the first four columns but you get the jist, it would need to be extended for as many columns as you need

Comment: Yeah, this works but definitely not the most elegant

Comment: @RayBritton added a second option to keep the spreadsheet clean from helper columns